# How can i change submit button id based on selected dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to change submit button id based on selected dropdown without submit.If i selected Live Bookmark ,the id of submit button should change to A1 without submit.How can i do that.Can anybody suggest.Below is my code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                       <select id="one" name="sub" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction()">
                          <option value="0">Select</option>
                          <option value="H1" id="A1" >Live Bookmark</option>
                          <option value="H2" id="A2">My Yahoo</option>
                          <option value="H3" id="A3">My Free Dictionary</option>
                          <option value="H4" id="A4">My Daily Rotation</option>
                          <option value="H5" id="A5">My Podnova</option>
                       </select>
                    </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                       <button type="submit" name="submit" id="$id">Subscribe Now</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>

              </div>
           </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Change id may cause error in javascript which refer this id. Why not have two buttons, according the selection show one of them.

Comment: If you want to set the same ID in your same form, you will not get the valid result on jquery. It's better to set unique ID on your form. You can do, If you select Live Bookmark then your submit button ID should be "H1" or something else, Not "A1" or not any ID which one already exists in your form.

Comment: I have posted the answer that exactly works for you

Comment: @iamnoten Can you give example or rebuilt the above code as per your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for a `change` event in select dropdown and assign the `id` attribute dynamically as shown in the code snippet below:

```js
$('document').ready(function(){

$('#one').on('change', function() {
  $('button[type=submit]').attr('id', $(this).find(":selected").attr('id'));
  console.log('Button Id is '+ $(this).find(":selected").attr('id'));
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                       <select id="one" name="sub" class="form-control">
                          <option value="0">Select</option>
                          <option value="H1" id="A1" >Live Bookmark</option>
                          <option value="H2" id="A2">My Yahoo</option>
                          <option value="H3" id="A3">My Free Dictionary</option>
                          <option value="H4" id="A4">My Daily Rotation</option>
                          <option value="H5" id="A5">My Podnova</option>
                       </select>
                    </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                       <button type="submit" name="submit" id="$id">Subscribe Now</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>

              </div>
           </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Thanks. Remember me for any help in front end

Answer (score 2):

```
function myFunction(id){
  var thisElem = $("#"+id);
  var selectedValue = $.trim(thisElem.val());
  //console.log(selectedValue);
   $("button[type=submit]").attr("id", selectedValue);
}

<select id="one" name="sub" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(this.id);">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="H1" id="A1" >Live Bookmark</option>
  <option value="H2" id="A2">My Yahoo</option>
  <option value="H3" id="A3">My Free Dictionary</option>
  <option value="H4" id="A4">My Daily Rotation</option>
  <option value="H5" id="A5">My Podnova</option>
  </select>

<button type="submit" name="submit" id="$id">Subscribe Now</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your submit button and remove the  `onchange="myFunction()"` if want to do that by jquery events. otherwise put that code in `myFunction`.

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="test" id="">Subscribe Now</button>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#one").change(function () {
        $(".test").attr('id', $(this).children(":selected").attr("id"));
    })
})
```

Here is the working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/tkqaujdb/)

Comment: Why to make use of an extra class? when we have several ways by which we can select the `submit` button using jquery

Comment: Glad to know that.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way with pure javascript:

Place the JavaScript function to change id in the `<head>` of the HTML page.

```
<head>
<script>
    function myFunction(new_id) {
        if (new_id == 0) {
            return // this is so that if "select" is selected then id won't change
        }
        // change id
        document.getElementsByName("submit")[0].id = new_id;
    }
</script>
</head>
```

Then modify your `<select>` as follows to call the function with the new id when selection changes.

```
<select id="one" name="sub" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(this.value);">
```

The whole code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title> new document </title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <script>
        function myFunction(new_id) {
            if (new_id == 0) {
                return;
            }
            document.getElementsByName("submit")[0].id = new_id;
            
            // test new id
            // remove this after testing
            alert(document.getElementById(new_id).id);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                       <select id="one" name="sub" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
                          <option value="0">Select</option>
                          <option value="H1" id="A1" >Live Bookmark</option>
                          <option value="H2" id="A2">My Yahoo</option>
                          <option value="H3" id="A3">My Free Dictionary</option>
                          <option value="H4" id="A4">My Daily Rotation</option>
                          <option value="H5" id="A5">My Podnova</option>
                       </select>
                    </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                       <button type="submit" name="submit" id="">Subscribe Now</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>

              </div>
           </div>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Working